# MVC3 ajax post mutliple checkbox values to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Using MVC3 I am trying to accomplish the following. I have a table which has a number of values, using ajax I want to be able to select the remove checkbox (for any number of rows) which is part of the table.

The using ajax post the result to the controller for processing. The issue I currently have is I cannot get the controller to accept the data coming from the ajax post.

I am making use of jQuery and json to make the ajax call.

```
function removeRooms() {
    var jdata = { 'mRooms': [] };
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        jdata['mRooms'].push($(this).val());        })

    $.ajax({
        url: "/room/removeselectedroom/@Model.mRoomid",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: jdata,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#mRooms').html(msg);
        }
    })
}
```

Any help you can give or resources would be appreciated.

EDIT:: One extra thing. I am getting through a IEnumerable object but there is a parameter an item in position one of the list with the value 'on' strange as there is only numbers in my checkboxes.

Comment: can you post the controller code

Comment: place the debugger at the start of your controller and see if ever the debugger is hit? i think the `url` part should be like `url:"/controllername/action/"+@model.roomid`

Comment: The controller is being hit the answer given by @danielb solved the intital question. As stated in my edit I now have a random value appearing in the IEnumerable<string> object which is not part of anything on my view form.

Comment: Is there a checkbox without a `value` attribute?

Comment: Thanks this has now been solved. The reason was a checkbox which was hidden on the page. I have now excluded this from the result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to serialize the data with `traditional: true`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/room/removeselectedroom/@Model.mRoomid",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: jdata,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#mRooms').html(msg);
    }
})
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) some information about array serialization.

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;.

ASP.Net MVC model binding requires array data in form of

```
mRooms=1&mRooms=2&mRooms=3
```

But from jQuery 1.4 it sends

```
mRooms[]=1&mRooms[]=2&mRooms[]=3
```

This is why you have to use `traditional: true`

Comment: You legend that is what I was looking for. What is it the traditional = true does?