# Send value of couple checkboxes to controller by jQuery.post() method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I have a table that displays from db all infrastructures (their name, description, performance). The last column of this table has checkbox. After selecting a few checkboxes, I want to have one button, which will delete all selected infrastructures. Here you have code of the table.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Nazwa //name
    </th>
    <th>
        Opis // description
    </th>
    <th>
        Wydajność // performance
    </th>
    <th>
        zaznacz  // select
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nazwa)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Opis)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wydajnosc) j
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%;">
            <input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' name='Infrastuktura[@item.InfrastrukturaID].myCheckbox' value='@item.InfrastrukturaID' />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I know that I need to have some variable, which will save all value from checkboxes. I had something like that: ( but it didnt't work well )

```
var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]#myCheckbox').attr('checked');
```

And then I must send this data ( using for example jQuery.post() ), I wrote a few functions, which send post with data, but none of them work properly. Below I put one of those functions:

```
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
    if (checked) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/InfrastrukturaDelete',
            data: 'id: ' +checked,
            contentType: 'json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("ble");
    }
});
```

Here is my method in HomeController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InfrastrukturaDelete(int[] myCheckbox)
    {
        foreach (int item in myCheckbox)
        {
            Infrastruktury infrastruktura = naukaRepository.GetInfrastruktura(item);
            naukaRepository.DeleteInfrastruktura(infrastruktura);
            naukaRepository.Save();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("InfrastrukturyView");
    }
```

I always get error 500 or Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined. Also if you can, show me how controller should look, to handle this ajax function. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My td with checkbox looks like that:

```
<td style="padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%;">
     <input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' name='InfrastukturaID' value='@item.InfrastrukturaID' />
</td>
```

My script with post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow() {
        if ($(':checkbox:checked')) {
            var postData = $('input[type="checkbox"]').serialize();
            $.post('/Home/InfrastrukturaDelete', postData,
            function () {
                $(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                    if (this.checked) {
                        $(this).closest('tr').detach();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Third argument in $.post() is function which dynamically delete tr, which contains checked checkboxes. My action in controller looks like that:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InfrastrukturaDelete(int[] InfrastukturaID)
    {
        foreach (int item in InfrastukturaID)
        {
                Infrastruktury infrastruktura = naukaRepository.GetInfrastruktura(item);
                naukaRepository.DeleteInfrastruktura(infrastruktura);
                naukaRepository.Save();
        }
        return Content("OK");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. I think you are looking for a way to post the ID's of the checked infrastructures.

In that case this is what I would do:

1. change the name of the input checkboxs to a non-variable value (ex. "Infrastuktura[@item.InfrastrukturaID].myCheckbox" becomes "InfrastukturaID")
2. Using jquery post method, post the data as form data back to the url.

   ```
   $('#submitButton').click(function () {
       $.post('/Home/InfrastrukturaDelete', 
              $("input[type='checkbox']").serialize(),
              function (msg) {
                  $('#mRooms').html(msg);
              })
       );
   });
   ```

This will not post your data as json data (you did not mention that as a requirement). Instead you will get a query string posted to the url. See more about .serialize() at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

With a single name for all the checkboxes, the query string posted will look something like this:

```
InfrastukturaID=ID1&InfrastukturaID=ID2&InfrastukturaID=ID5
```

This should then not be too hard to loop through server side to perform the deletes.

Server side I would perform the loop like this (sorry I code vb not c# but you should be able to translate):

```
For Each id As String In Request.Form("InfrastrukturaID")
    'try convert string to int ID
    'perform delete operation using the id
Next
    'submit/save changes for delete operation
```

I used string in the loop instead of int since you have to make sure you can cast to int first. Can't trust the data will always be what you intend it to.

Comment: You understood me perfect ( I want to post the id's of the checked infrastructures ). I tried to do it, like you wrote. Still "error 500 Internal Server Error" and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". My POST looks like this: InfrastukturaID=24&InfrastukturaID=25 ( it looks good ). Maybe something wrong with my method in controller?.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it is helpful, this is the first answer I've given on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to serialize the data with `traditional: true`

Taken from this in [mvc3-ajax-post-mutliple-checkbox-values-to-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666630/mvc3-ajax-post-mutliple-checkbox-values-to-controller) ,It might be helpful to you...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/room/removeselectedroom/@Model.mRoomid",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: jdata,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#mRooms').html(msg);
    }
})
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) some information about array serialization.

> As of jQuery 1.4, the $.param() method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;.

Comment: Even though I used "traditional: true" in my post method, console in Chrome shows Error 500 and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. It see mistake somewhere in my controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Does using `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` work?

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    if (checked) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/InfrastrukturaDelete',
            data: 'id: ' +checked,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //<--- Change here
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("ble");
    }
});
```